# why marquee tag not working in google chrome.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert an image into marquee tag.

I have written following code:

```
<marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="alternate" direction="right" width="300"><img width="180px" style="padding-left:30px;opacity:0.7" src="img/cloud3.png"></marquee>
```

Its working fine in firefox and IE but not working in chrome.
What is the problem.?
Please reply as early as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help.

Comment: I am able to see only image but it is not scrolling.

Comment: ****Used to jScroller** ** **[jScroller Link](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/)**

Answer (score 20):

Because the `marquee` tag is a crime against nature. And it's no longer supported in newer versions of Chrome.

Comment: He's trying to make an image scroller, which I believe is also a crime against nature, but perhaps, not so much, but it's quite common.

Comment: I find this answer rather bland. The `marquee` tag should probably never have been created but with web components someone could easily create a new `marquee` tag today. The point is that html is all about semantics not presentation. `marquee` decides how something should be displayed not what type of information it is. The end result of a `marquee` tag isn't what's bad here. It's how it's created that's bad.  HTML shouldn't be part of the presentation, that's what's wrong with `marquee`.

Answer (score 10):

The `marquee` is not supported in modern html. Chrome dropped support for it a while ago. You need to implement this via CSS3 or Javascript.

Further W3C states that it is [non standard](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee) and should not be used.

The effect can be easily acheived via [jQuery](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) or via [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/)

Answer (score 4):

The `marquee` element has varying implementations, partly because there has been no published specification for it. In HTML5, the element is being defined exactly, and HTML5 drafts *require* support to [`marquee` as defined there](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0). (The drafts also declare it “obsolete” and “nonconforming”, but these are just what they say to *authors*; the requirements on *implementations* are different.) However, there are still limitations and differences in support, see e.g. [MDN on `marquee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee).

In this case, it does not seem to be the image but the attribute `behavior="alternate"` that causes the problem. If you remove it, the image will move on Chrome, too.

This is apparently implementation *bug* rather than lack of support. Inspecting the DOM in Chrome shows that the `behavior` property has the value `alternate` as specified, but it just does not work. If you add a border to the `marquee` element in CSS, the image starts moving, alternatingly, but just a few pixels right and left.

If you really alternating direction, it is probably best to use some other technique instead of `marquee`. For example, a simple moving image can be implemented using JavaScript so that the position is changed in a loop, using a timer, and then you can easily implement alternating direction, too. Alternatively, possibly simpler but not as robustly (due to limited browser support), you can use CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="cloud">image</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #cloud{
        width:180px;
        padding-left:30px;
        opacity:0.7;
        animation:slide 10s infinite;
        -moz-animation:slide 10s infinite;//Firefox
        -webkit-animation:slide 10s infinite;//chrome and safari
        -o-animation: slide 10s infinite;//Opera   
}

@keyframes slide{
    0%   {-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
        100% {-transform: translate(500px,0px); }
}    

@-moz-keyframes spin{
    0%   {-moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
    100% {-moz-transform: translate(500px, 0px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
         0%   {-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
        100% {    -webkit-transform: translate(500px,0px); }
    }

@-o-keyframes slide{
    0%   {-o-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
    100% {-o-transform: translate(500px, 0px); }
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qCahH

Replace the text with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Marquee has been deprecated so will show unspecified behaviour on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Who said it doesn't ? 
On Chromium 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit) it works flawlessly.

Didn't test on Chrome, though.